# Upper bound for smallest eigenvalue of infinite family of graphs

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, sp.spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $\left\{G_{n}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of regular simple connected graphs with at least one edge such that $G_i$ is an induced sub-graph of $G_{i+1}$ and is not equal to $G_{i+1}$.

Is there a constant $c<0$ such that for large enough $i$ the smallest eigenvalue of $G_{i}$ is smaller or equal to $c$? In other words, can the sequance of smallest eigenvalues of $G_{n}$ approach to $0$?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know regular graphs of smallest eigenvalue arbitrarily close to 0?

Comment: But a graph with minimum eigenvalue at least $-1$ is a disjoint union of cliques, so you can’t have smallest eigenvalues near $0$.